# Create a backup before deleting each file in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I have a folder which has several files with .txt extension. I need to delete them but before that I need to take backup of it.

For example, assume I have a folder with the following contents:

```
name1.txt  
name2.txt   
name3.txt   
name4.txt
```

After I delete, the contents of my folder should be:

```
name1.txt.bkup  
name2.txt.bkup  
name3.txt.bkup  
name4.txt.bkup
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `rename *.txt *.txt.bkup` ?

Comment: Just rename the files to X.bkup ?

Comment: Can you put them in a directory?  If not, you need to build a string.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your title. Don't post questions with your caps lock key engaged. It isn't considered good etiquette.

Comment: @Edward. Sorry. I did not notice the Caps lock getting turned on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename .txt-files to .txt.bkup, i.e.:

```
rename *.txt *.txt.bkup
```

---

If you *insist* on creating backups before deleting (for example, a configurable batch file, where creating backups may be switched off), then you can copy files before deleting:

```
copy *.txt *.txt.bkup
del *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
copy *.txt *.txt.bkup
del *.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 for /r "C:\**" %%i  in (*.txt) do  rename %%i %%i.bkup
del *.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work. the `for /r` path parameter can't have wildcards.